# IBM Mobilefirst 8.0 Server installation issue on DEV enviroment

Tags: server, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I'm installing IBM Mobilefirst 8.0 on DEV enviroment.

I followed steps available in IBM portal as below.

http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/production/tutorials/command-line/
http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/production/

However i installed IBM Mobilefirst Installation Manager and WebSphere Liberty Core on DEV enviroment.

While installing MFP server we are getting below error:

```
./imcl install com.ibm.mobilefirst.foundation.server_8.0.0.20170911_1450 -repositories /data3/opt/IBM/MFP_Server/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/disk1 -properties user.appserver.selection2=none,user.database.selection2=none,user.database.preinstalled=false,user.licensed.by.tokens=false,user.use.ios.edition=false -acceptLicense



***********************************************************************
Before you start using the product, you must deploy a MobileFirst Server to your application server.
For more information about deploying projects with the Server Configuration Tool or command line tools, see
the documentation at https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/production/appserver/.
***********************************************************************
ERROR: Failed to find required installation files.
  CRIMA1161E ERROR: Failed to find required installation files.

  Explanation: Installation Manager did not find required installation files from the repository. An issue has occurred with the package that cannot be resolved by Installation Manager.

  User Action: If the repository files were transferred from a different location before the installation, verify that the files were not altered during the transfer operation. Copy the repository files to a different location and install from that location. If the repository files were not transferred note the package name and version number and contact customer support.
    ERROR: 'zip com.ibm.imp.apacheant 1.9.4' not found in /data3/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/disk1.
```

server details:
JAVA 1.7
Linux Redhat 6.8
Websphere Liberty core and IBM Installation Manager
ant 1.9.4

is there anything which i m missing?

Comment: What if you try "./imcl install com.ibm.mobilefirst.foundation.server -repositories /data3/opt/IBM/MFP_Server/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/disk1 -properties user.appserver.selection2=none,user.database.selection2=none,user.database.preinstalled=false,user.licensed.by.tokens=false,user.use.ios.edition=false -acceptLicense"

Comment: yes i tried with that as well but didn't worked. I download again repository and now its working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in the comments, the issue was possible corruption of the binary downloaded the first time - during download or transfer.

Downloading the same repository again and trying resolves the issue.